# JQ remove the output commas between data

Tags: jq

Hello i'm trying to extract this data below

```
{
    "a": "orlando, florida, united states",
    "t": ["007-414-7001", "1-007-414-7002", "0074147003", "1-007-414-7005"],
    "e": ["demo@example.com", "demo1@example.com", "demo2@example.com", "demo3@example.com"],
    "liid": "empty",
    "linkedin": "empty",
    "n": "phil demo"
}
```

my command is `jq -r '[.e[], .t[], .n, .linkedin, .a] | @tsv'`
So i got an output like this

```
demo@example.com        demo1@example.com       demo2@example.com       demo3@example.com       007-414-7001   1-007-414-7002  0074147003      1-007-414-7005  phil demo       empty   orlando, florida, united states
```

*As you can see for "e" field its just one column but in csv or tsv result give multiple columns not just one.*

My question now how i can get between data in both fields of "e" and "t" separated by commas?

I need to get a result like this:

```
demo@example.com,demo1@example.com,demo2@example.com,demo3@example.com       007-414-7001,1-007-414-7002,0074147003,1-007-414-7005  phil demo       empty   orlando, florida, united states
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Update-assignment operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Assignment) `|=` to modify the values of "e" and "t".

```
jq -r '.e |= join(",")
     | .t |= join(",")
     | [.e, .t, .n, .linkedin, .a]
     | @tsv'
```